# INSERT into an identity column not allowed on table variables

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am importing data from large excel sheet and storing it in a stateTable. Now I have to push this data into a database table. The table does have an identity column(1,1).

I have created a similar table type in DB and a procedure to take a parameter as table type to insert in the particular table. I have also set ON the identity insert.

My code is:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("InsertStateTable") {
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure})
{
    SqlParameter param = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statetable", dt);
    param.TypeName = "StateTable";
    param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    command.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

But the error that arises is
**"INSERT into an identity column not allowed on table variables."**
I have gone thru many sites but no specific reason is given.....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you "set ON the identity insert" ? do you mean globally? because the per-table syntax doesn't work for table-variables / table-valued-parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is fairly clear: you are not allowed to do what you are trying to do. Basically, you are going to have to find a design that is not dependent on inserting the identity value into the table-variable / table-valued-parameter. My advice would be to create a separate table-variable (unrelated to the table-valued-parameter) which has the same *data*, but which does not have the `IDENTITY` column, so...

```
declare @foo table (id int not null, name nvarchar(200) not null /* etc */)
insert @foo (id, name /* etc */)
select id, name /* etc */ from @statetable
```

at which point `@foo` has the original data, but does not have an identity column - you can then do whatever you want with `@foo`.

Without seeing what you are doing with your identity insert, it is hard to comment much further.

Comment: Is there any other method to insert a datatable populated from excel sheets into a Sql Server database.

Comment: @VeerB.Singh `SqlBulkCopy` ?

Comment: Thanks Marc . It works fine with Sqlbulkcopy. To insert identity key you have to use SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity